# Netlify/ git LFS exit status 128

Tags: reactjs, git, frontend, netlify, git-lfs

So on my netlify website, I'm trying to upload a video thats over 300mb(12 minutes long) and have it posted to the page. I had to use Git LFS to push my mp4 file to github. Now when I go to deplot my site I get the exit status 128 and its saying this in my deploy log

```
4:54:27 PM: Error checking out branch: Downloading public/Videos/PythonCalc.mp4 (368 MB)
Error downloading object: public/Videos/PythonCalc.mp4 (adfdf37): Smudge error: Error downloading public/Videos/PythonCalc.mp4 (adfdf371e863741df3af4755413fae738891f5c794f28fd5564879b2a7ddb35b): batch request: missing protocol: ""


Errors logged to /opt/build/repo/.git/lfs/logs/20220121T005427.736137478.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: public/Videos/PythonCalc.mp4: smudge filter lfs failed
4:54:27 PM: Creating deploy upload records
4:54:27 PM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
4:54:27 PM: Failed during stage 'preparing repo': exit status 128
4:54:28 PM: Finished processing build request in 8.446701277s
```

I just figured out how to use LFS and when I started looking into the error its saying netlify doesnt have permission? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup netlify to support large media by running
`netlify lm:setup`. It will verify and install everything you need and generate a `.lfsconfig` file.

See [Netlify Large Media Documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/large-media/setup/)